# Have sqlite3 pre-installed on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, sqlite

I am using a NodeJS stack on Heroku and everything usually works fine, but for my current project, I require the `sqlite3` binary which I can't get to work on Heroku.

I tried the following:

- Install using apt (permission error)
- Install pre-compiled binary (It says the file is missing despite <kbd>Tab</kbd> yelling me the path to it.
- Compile from source (`Makefile` just wouldn't work and complain about missing files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up forking the NodeJS buildpack and adding sqlite3 to it that way.

https://github.com/EtudieCA/heroku-buildpack-nodejs-sqlite3